# Copying from multiple subdirectories to a single folder using python

Tags: python, windows, directory, copy

So I'm trying to copy files within multiple folders into one folder using python. This is the code I currently have.

```
import os
import shutil

    path = r'C:\Users\George\OneDrive\Documents\USB Backup\Home working\Work' + '\\'

    target = r'C:\Users\George\OneDrive\Documents\USB Backup\Code\target' + '\\'

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
       if files:
          for file in files:
             if ((file.endswith(".xlsm")) or (file.endswith(".xlsx"))) and (file.__contains__("note")):
                 if not os.path.isfile(target +file):
                    os.rename(path + file, target + file)
```

This code currently moves the file from the 'Work' folder, but I want to just **copy** from multiple folders within the 'Work' folder. Please help.

Comment: Take a look at copyfile from the shutil module

Comment: Please, improve your question format.